# A way to deploy plsql to Oracle in Java project with Maven build tool

Tags: java, oracle, maven, plsql

I join to project where plsql sources developed and stored in Oracle DB.

There are two copies of sources - on test and on production servers. So SPOT (single point of trust) rule was broken. Copies require synchronisation from time to time and this job is performed manually.

But most annoying thing come from configuration management - I can't reproduce previous working project copy because old plsql scripts was lost (new version have changes in API).

After studying subject I found awesome project: https://code.google.com/p/plsqlmaven

By following https://code.google.com/p/plsqlmaven/wiki/Basics I can dump all plsql scrips (and diff between production and testing) from DB'es:

```
  $ mvn plsql:extract -Dforce
```

but I stuck with **plsql:deploy** command (it print error about missing jars, I don't understand how to create it). I will contact to author soon and will fill some bug reports.

But I hope that community already solve such basic task for project vitality.

How can I deploy plsql scripts to Oracle DB in Java project (my project uses Maven build system)?

**PS** I look to SQL Developer tutorials on oracle.com - I can't find how to deploy entirely plsql files hierarchy by one button click. And I prefer command line solution...

**PPS** I report related errors to **plsqlmaven** project:

- https://code.google.com/p/plsqlmaven/issues/detail?id=4 (Need tutorial for deploying plsql files to Oracle DB.)
- https://code.google.com/p/plsqlmaven/issues/detail?id=5 (Please release 1.11 to Maven central.)
- https://code.google.com/p/plsqlmaven/issues/detail?id=6 (*plsql:extract* dump plsql code to src/main/java by default in 1.10)

**PPPS** I ask question at http://rsdn.ru/forum/java/5011849.flat (Russian)

Comment: Consider including actual error text.  They tend to contain inportant information.

Comment: I will do this when back to job tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the situations I'd love to use [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/), as it lets you manage version and scripts.

It is also handy when testing, as it lets you seed the database into a given state.

Comment: I will look dipper for this solution soon. I am interesting in Oracle suppoort. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2):

How about old good SQL Plus? Create master script that will call others as required, and pass it from command line to `sqlplus` (you'll need Oracle client installed on machine though). jisql is a command-line java sql tool - but don't think it has an option of calling sub-scripts. Running commands from maven is fairly easy with exec plugin.

Comment: That seems a solution but not in Maven way... I ask local Oracle experts about **sqlplus** abilities. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't make deep look to:

- http://flywaydb.org
- http://www.liquibase.org/

but seems these projects provide not only solution for my problem but more complex solution for another related problems.

Both have Maven integration and Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

You should use plsql:compile not plsql:deploy:

```
mvn -Pyourdbprofile plsql:compile
```

ps: Take a look at [par](https://github.com/aaaristo/par) if you need a way to deploy an archive.